# Interação com widgets Checkbutton do tkinter no python3

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou criando um sistema em python3 usando a biblioteca tkinter, preciso que ao marcar o widget Checkbutton "Marcar Todos" os demais sejam marcados e ao desmarcar, os demais sejam desmarcados.

segue abaixo o código:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

check01 = Checkbutton(master, text="Marcar Todos")
check01.place(x=50,y=50)
check01.deselect()

check02 = Checkbutton(master, text='Opcao 01')
check02.place(x=50,y=90)
check02.deselect()

check03 = Checkbutton(master, text='Opcao 02')
check03.place(x=50,y=110)
check03.deselect()

master.geometry("200x200")

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui encontrar a solução, segue abaixo:

from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

def marcatodos():
    global estado, estado2
    if estado.get() > 0:
        check02.select()
        check03.select()
    else:
        check02.deselect()
        check03.deselect()

def desmarca():
    check01.deselect()

estado = IntVar()
check01 = Checkbutton(master, text="Marcar Todos", command=marcatodos, variable=estado)
check01.place(x=50,y=50)
check01.deselect()

check02 = Checkbutton(master, text='Opcao 01', command=desmarca)
check02.place(x=50,y=90)
check02.deselect()

check03 = Checkbutton(master, text='Opcao 02', command=desmarca)
check03.place(x=50,y=110)
check03.deselect()

master.geometry("200x200")
master.mainloop()